How to restrict access to resources accessed via API Gateway using Cognito Custom Attributes
I have an app with a Cognito user base that has a custom attribute called "Tenant". I want to use this attribute to help me control the dynamoDB tables that are relevant to that user's tenant, so that user can only see tables "belong" to that tenant.
My app calls an API Gateway resource, which then uses a lambda to make a PutItem request to my DynamoDB Table. What I want to do, is to use the value of my "Tenant" custom attribute to control what tables the cognito user should have access to. I have tried doing this via Principal tags, by adding a mapping under the attributes for access control table in the user pool's relevant identity pool's identity provider. But it seems that is not possible because when the API Gateway calls the Lambda the values in those Principal tags is gone as the Lambda does not seem to have access to the calling session.
I have a condition such as below in my Lambda just as proof of concept, but I am getting an unauthorized error, I assume from the limitation I mention above.
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "aws:PrincipalTag/TenantValue": "myTenantValue"
    }
} 

Is my use case above possible? How do I restrict access for an API invoked lambda based on the attributes of the cognito user calling the API Gateway?

Maybe the documentation helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html  -> $context.authorizer.claims['Tenant']

Hey there, that looks like documentation for authenticating usage of the API itself. I have actually already done that with a Cognito Authorizer. What I am trying to do from that point is to control what resources the API has access to based on the context of the caller.

I was referring to the format, how to get values from the context. But, I don't get, what you want to control on the IAM level. You cannot define IAM rights for the Lambda dynamically. If it's about which "Tenant"-value the Lambda uses, then you can work with the context which is passed to the Lambda. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/typescript-context.html

I am trying to do something similar to this link. I am aware that is probably a role policy as opposed to a resource policy, but what I am trying to achieve is to use the attributes from the cognito user to define what DynamoDB Tables the lambda should have access to.  Something like
"Condition : {"aws:PrincipalTag/TenantValue": "tenantAttributefromCognitoUser"} in the role the lambda uses but it looks like the lambda context does not retain info about the cognito user

(Ran out of characters) I am trying to understand if it is possible for the lambda to get those attributes from the principal tag? I can ofc get them from the JWT token that I use as part of the cognito authorizer and implement bespoke authorization myself, but am hoping to use AWS' native IAM to help bolster security

Pretty sure, that the data from Cognito will be available in the Lambda when the proxy integration is used (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55941730/577483). Maybe you can use the same path (authorizer.claims...) for the IAM rule.

Unfortunately the authorizer.claims... path is for access the data of the user from cognito within the Lambda app, that is not accessible in the IAM policy. I have tried it just to be thorough but AWS will not let you save the policy due to errors.
